# Why is Saturday a typical slow day for airlines? Not weekends, but Saturdays?

Tags: airline-operations

Why are Saturdays typically slower days for airlines? I have always heard that they are but never a reason why.

Comment: A good majority of passengers are business passengers, who don't really want to travel on their days off.

Comment: The airlines fly less when people want to fly less. Why do people want to fly less on Saturdays? That's probably better for Travel.SE. I'd say it's because business travellers make up a huge percentage of airline passengers and they don't need to fly on Saturdays. Sunday afternoons are usually busy as they get to where they need to be for Monday morning.

Comment: Saturday is indeed slow day. Sundays are full of people getting back from holidays, or before the working week. Mon-Fri are people travelling on business, or (for Friday) back home before weekend.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Wouldn't their days off be the only days when they'd have time available to fly?

Comment: @Sean No, because they want to be home on the weekends and do "work activities" during paid work days. So usually a business traveler will travel on Monday's (to the site) and Fridays (home) so that they have the weekend with their friends/families. I wouldn't want to travel home on Saturday and back out on Sunday, there would be no point...